# win10 Windows Security, how to disable "Real-time protection" permanently?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender

every time i turn off Real-time protection, its off for a few days (maybe 3 days?) then it automatically turns itself on again, how do i stop it? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note: I believe this solution requires Windows 10 Pro***

First, you need to disable *Tamper Protection*, if you haven't already:

-Double-click the Windows Defender shield icon in the system tray.

-Choose *Virus & Threat Protection*

-Click *Manage Settings* down the bottom

-Switch off the *Tamper Protection* switch.

Now you can disable Windows Defender, as described in the next section

---

To disable Windows Defender:

-Press WIN, type *gpedit.msc* and hit ENTER to open *Local Group Policy Editor*

-In the left panel, locate: *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft Defender Antivirus* and left click on it

-Then in the right panel find an option called *Turn Off Microsoft Defender Antivirus* and double-click it

-Check *Enabled* and click OK.

-Restart your Computer. The yellow shield will still likely be there in the system tray, but Windows Defender (including real-time protection) should be off.

---

As a side note, if you install a third-party antivirus program, Windows Defender will disable itself automatically.